# What is the easest way return objects as json response from action in play framework (scala)?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm new to scala and play framework.

Why does scala not have something like this??

```
  class Customer (idx: Int, emailx: String) {
     val id: Int = idx
     val email: String = emailx
  }

  ....

  def customers = Action {
    val customer = new Customer(1, "Customer1")       
    Ok(Json.toJson(customer))
  }
```

I like play frameowrk (with scala, its productivity)

But,

Why should I map each field of my object manulay to json field?? Was it so hard for scala to implement this future like in Java or C#, even php has json_encode.

Is there any way to achieve this simple goal (return object as json) without any additional manipulations?

Answer (score 3):

Macros are slick and perfect for generating simple case class formats

```
implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[Customer]
```

Typically you put this declaration in your companion object to the type you are generating a format for. This way it is implicitly in scope in any file that you import your type (`Customer`). Like this:

```
case class Customer(...)
object Customer {
  implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[Customer]
}
```

Then in your controller you can do

```
Json.toJson(customer)
```

which will produce the `JsValue` type expected by Play.

Answer (score 2):

For my classes I define a convertor, so that I can write exactly what you have written, e.g. `Json.toJson(customer)`, but the convertor, though simple, does currently have to be written once. E.g.

```
implicit val customerWrites = new Writes[Customer] {
  def writes(customer:Customer) = Json.obj(
    "id" -> customer.id,
    "email" -> customer.email
  )
}
```

Perhaps macros, into which I have not delved, could do this more automatically...

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. You should change `new Writes[Customer] = {` to `new Writes[Customer] {`. I would make the edit myself but the change is less than the 6 required characters so I cannot.

Comment: @Asa Tks for picking that up.